# In RxJS what's the difference between error callback vs .catch()?

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5, angular-httpclient

If I have code like the below:

```
const d: any = {};

return this.http.post(url, body, httpOptions).map(data => {
  return d;
}, error => {
  console.error('error');
})
.catch((err, d$) => {
  return Observable.of(d);
});
```

and if there is any kind of error i.e. the POST request failed or some error in the `.map()` success callback or any other kind of error.

Which of the two error handlers would be invoked the error callback on the `.map()` or the `.catch()` callback? Is it dependent on the type of the error that might happen?

Would the error callback on the `.map()` be skipped always because of the presence of the `.catch()` operator?

Comment: This case there will be an error, since RxJS is about observables which should be subscribed to.

Comment: Also, why do you ask 'what will be invoked' meanwhile you can just try it yourself? Nothing crucial will happen to you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example the catch would be invoked if an error occurred. Additionally, the `map` operator does not have a second argument so that function will never be called. If you have an error handler on a subscribe then the callback will be invoked if an unhandled exception occurs. The `catchError` operator is a way of handling errors. It basically acts as a `switchMap` to switch to a new observable stream.

### Examples:

#### Subscribe Error Handler ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-6yrczn?embed=1&file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100))

```js
return throwError('This is an error!').subscribe(data => {
  console.log("Got Data: ", data);
}, error => {
  console.error('error', error); // Observable stream has error so this prints
});
```

#### Catching an error ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-g1ackn?embed=1&file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100))

```js
return throwError('This is an error!').pipe(
  catchError(error => {
    console.log("Error Caught", error);
    return of(2); // Catches the error and continues the stream with a value of 2
  }),
).subscribe(data => {
  console.log("Got Data: ", data); // Data will be logged
}, error => {
  console.error('error', error); // Will not be called
});
```

#### Catching an error and re-throwing ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pus7t8?embed=1&file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100))

```js
return throwError('This is an error!').pipe(
  catchError(error => {
    console.log("Error Caught", error);
    return throwError(error); // Catches the error and re-throws
  }),
).subscribe(data => {
  console.log("Got Data: ", data);
}, error => {
  console.error('error', error); // Observable stream has error so this prints
});
```

Comment: what about catch and catchError, is it much different?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest - I never seen such syntax and I asume its wrong:

```
.map(data => {
  return d;
}, error => {
```

`error` is one of the three Observable's `subscribe()` method callbacks. It fires once - if error happens. But **Rxjs** `catch` operator returns an **Observable**. Thats the main difference - you can relay on it to continue your stream.